# Windows- Installing Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

when installing Heroku CLI - I can only use the heroku in command line when I am inside \bin in my comand line. I have updated the environment variables and no other posts speak to this situation. - How can I have it act normally so I can use the commands while not in the \bin path, and actually use it for it's intended functionality. thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open windows bash and enter:
`PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/Heroku/bin"`

Heroku CLI should be added to path, you can test with:
`heroku --version`

Answer (score 0):

what about adding these C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin   in your environment variables path?

Comment: I did, the thing is also - it only downloaded as C:\Users\Patrick\bin - there was no "Heroku"

Comment: I just added bin to be behind Heroku and add this to my enviroment variables path: C:\Users\Patrick\AppData\Local\heroku\bin and still no dice